# Oracle SQL group by to_char - not a group by expression

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, to-char

I want to group by `dd-mm-yyyy` format to show `working_hours` per employee (person) per day, but I get error message `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`, when I remove `TO_CHAR` from `GROUP BY` it works fine, but that's not I want as I want to `group by` days regardless hours, what am I doing wrong here?

```
    SELECT   papf.person_number emp_id,
         to_char(sh21.start_time,'dd/mm/yyyy') start_time,
         to_char(sh21.stop_time,'dd/mm/yyyy') stop_time,
         SUM(sh21.measure) working_hours
    FROM per_all_people_f papf,
         hwm_tm_rec sh21
         
         

    WHERE ...

    GROUP BY 
         papf.person_number,
         to_char(sh21.start_time,'dd/mm/yyyy'),
         to_char(sh21.stop_time,'dd/mm/yyyy')

    ORDER BY sh21.start_time
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full and exact error message, ensuring that code shown is the ***exact*** code that generated the error message.  Then try a simplified query to debug your issue for example; `SELECT to_char(sh21.start_time,'dd/mm/yyyy') FROM hwm_tm_rec sh21 GROUP BY to_char(sh21.start_time,'dd/mm/yyyy') LIMIT 1`

Comment: ```ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression```

Comment: Not that it's required but SQL standers to support joins were changed in [1992](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92) to use different join syntax.  Usually makes reading SQL easier and easier to troubleshoot...

Comment: you are right, I usually use ```LEFT JOIN``` syntax, but this query is copy-pasted and will be refactored after completion.

Comment: It's the order by clause, you need to use the to_char expresssion here

Comment: @Andrew - Good spot!

Comment: just if it says something like ```not a selected expression``` would be much better...

Comment: It means that the expression in the ORDER BY isn't an expression (or derived from an expression) present in the GROUP BY, which it ***must*** be, if it's not an aggregate. I agree that it should say what LINE the "not a group by expression" is on, but not to change the terminology.

Comment: I don't know that any RDBMS will tell you what column(s) are missing from the group by, or where it is (or isn't?) in the query. The actual verbiage "not a group by expression" could be clearer, I guess.

Comment: For those who noted non-ANSI join: Oracle Business Suite uses it for decades, they do not change anything in view definitions even in recent versions and everything is joined via comma and awkward `(+)`. For example [PAY_BANK_ACCOUNTS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/human-resources/23a/oedmh/paybankaccounts-6680.html#paybankaccounts-6680). It may be a habit to do the same

Comment: its a bad habit tho, ANSI much clearer

Answer (score 0):

```sql
ORDER BY sh21.start_time
```

needs to either be just the column alias defined in the `SELECT` clause:

```sql
ORDER BY start_time
```

or use the expression in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```sql
ORDER BY to_char(sh21.start_time,'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

---

If you use `sh21.start_time` then the `table_alias.column_name` syntax refers to the underlying column from the table and you are not selecting/grouping by that.